# Java Jar file SoftLink in Linux

Tags: java, linux, bash, command, symlink

I have created a jar file , it reads from standard input and print them out to the standard output.

Below is how you can use the app:

```
cat /ephemeral/test/input | java -jar /ephemeral/test/Hello.jar >> /ephemeral/test/output
```

I am wondering is it possible to add my Hello.jar to be a Linux Command, let's say -hello-:

So next time I could just do something like:

```
hello /ephemeral/test/input /ephemeral/test/output
```

I am not that much familiar with Linux Soft Link and Java, so any help or information would be appricated!

UPDATE:
thanks for reno's inspiring answer, I put the cat ... | .. >> .. into a shell script hello.sh.
Now I can do something like:

```
./hello.sh /inputpath/input outputpath/output
```

(Note: you should not use $0, $0 is actually the name the file itself instead of input arguments)

Now, the last question is how could you access the shell script EVERYWHERE, like how you call basic shell cmds: ls..cat..echo..

I have read a [tutorial](http://linuxcommand.org/wss0010.php#path) described exactly what I want(reach to the end of the tutorial directly):

1. I did add the path of the directory where the hello.sh exists into the path variable.
2. I created a bin folder which is like mkdir /home/ubuntu/bin and put my shell script there. 
   However, I still have problem do what the author described:

   hello input output (in my case)

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write a shell script say test.sh and copy your code to test.sh

## !/bin/bash

cat $0 | java -jar /ephemeral/test/Hello.jar >> $1

and execute the script by passing your input and output file name something like this:

test.sh /ephemeral/test/input /ephemeral/test/output

Comment: $0 $1 is exactly what I need but the LINUX COMMAND problem has not been cleared. test.sh only works in the folder where the script exists right? how can you access test.sh regardless which folder you are.

Comment: You are right, test.sh executes only in the directory it is present in. If you want to execute it universally you can either use absolute path ex: /ephemeral/myfolder/test.sh :) or add add test.sh to bin folders. more information on how to make your script universal can be found in the below link,  http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/15764-making-your-script-universal.html

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to write a shell script (usually `hello.sh`) that contains the necessary `java -jar` command.

Comment: Hi chrylis, do you know which folder should I place my shell script(hello.sh) so that I could call it like the other shell commands: ls, cat, echo.... /usr/bin? /home/ubuntu/bin? ... Thanks!

Comment: Is this a command that's just for you, or are you making it available to everyone on the system? If it's yours, make a `$HOME/bin` directory and add it to the path. If it's for everyone, put it in `/usr/local/bin`.